# ConcurrentHashMap's get() Vs HashTable's get()

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

I read that both `ConcurrentHashMap`'s `get()` method as well as `HashTable`'s `get()` is thread safe, even though former does not use synchronized keyword.
Why in `HashTable`'s `get()` method implementation synchronized keyword is required to make it thread safe but it is not required in case of `ConcurrentHashMap`'s `get()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadly because `HashTable` and `ConcurrentHashMap` don't have **exactly** the same behavior and so actual results concerning concurrency. For retrieval operations, the fact that `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't lock the whole table makes  `ConcurrentHashMap` to may not reflect the last updated value for the key as `get()` may overlap with `put()`/`remove()` operations :

> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may
>   overlap with update operations (including put and remove). Retrievals
>   reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations
>   holding upon their onset

And when this delay doesn't matter in many use cases and also you can cope with that with explicit synchronized statements, you prefer to use `ConcurrentHashMap` over `HashTable` as it improves the overall `Map` performance for concurrent access.

Comment: It's probably just a wording problem, but my understanding of your answer is that it is backward: there is no delay when getting from a ConcurrentHashMap, since it doesn't block, and returns, immediately, based on the most recent completed updates. On the contrary, there can be a delay when getting from a Hashtable, since it blocks until it can obtain the lock, which can be held by other read or write operations.

Comment: @JB Nizet  Of course. The "delay" term to mean "not updated" is probably a bad shortcut, overall in this specific context where the real delay in terms of time comes from the other class : HashTable. Thanks for the remark.